# Why is the created csv file duplicating the row and how do I create the list as a column?

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to python and in trying to learn some basics I have a basic webscraper to grab URL links and then I want to write these to csv as a list in a single column.  However, in the code below, the links are written in a row (254 items) but then that entire row is duplicated the same number of times (254 identical rows). I've searched but cannot find the same issue.  Thanks for any help/understanding.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

r = requests.get('url')
print(r.status_code)
r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())

data=[]
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
    data.append(link['href'])

with open('test1.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    for row in data:
        write.writerow(data)
```

Comment: I typed in the wrong with open statement, I've updated it to the version I am using with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `write` being the writer object, you may want to try:

```
with open('test1.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    for row in data:
        write.writerow([row])  # [row] to write row as an unique column
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without the use of `csv`. Is not really needed or useful in this simple case.

```
with open("test1.txt", "w") as ff:
    for row in data:
        ff.write(row + '\n')
```